# Is it possible to match multiple IP addresses when using tc filter... match?

Tags: ip, traffic-shaping

I would like to `match` 4 IP addresses as `src` and other 4 IP addresses as `dst` when using `tc filter`

I do know I could use subnets in `match` but unfortunately my addresses does not form a subnet instead I have distinct IP addresses.

I have a working script with 1 IP address as `src` and 1 IP address as `dst`

```
export IF=enp0s8
export IP1=10.1.2.11
export IP2=10.1.2.15

tc qdisc del dev $IF root

tc qdisc add dev $IF root handle 1:0 htb
tc class add dev $IF parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb rate 20mbit 

tc filter add dev $IF protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst $IP1/32 match ip src $IP2/32 flowid 1:1
tc filter add dev $IF protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst $IP2/32 match ip src $IP1/32 flowid 1:1
```

Because I have 4 `src` and 4 `dst` IP addresses I can accomplish the task by adding total of 32 lines of `tc filter...` but I am not sure there is not more efficient way.

I've tried to google for `match` syntax with no success. As a guesswork here is what I've tried with no success:

```
export IPGROUP1=10.1.2.11, 10.1.2.12, 10.1.2.13, 10.1.2.14
export IPGROUP2=10.1.2.15, 10.1.2.16, 10.1.2.17, 10.1.2.18

tc filter add dev $IF protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst $IPGROUP1 match ip src $IPGROUP2 flowid 1:1
tc filter add dev $IF protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst $IPGROUP2 match ip src $IPGROUP1 flowid 1:1
```

Comment: Have you looked at [man 8 iptables](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables)

Comment: many thx. I was looking for command `tc˛`. Anyway I found something promising: `--src-range ip-ip` ...

Comment: I removed iptables tag, as I am using tc command. I could not figure out how the iptables --src-range syntax could be applied to tc